# Why is this an open condition of vector bundles?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $S$ be a smooth projective K3 surface. Let $E$ be a vector bundle on $S$ of rank $r+1$ with determinant $L$ such that

a) $H^i(S,E) =0$ for $i=1,2$ and 
b) there exists a $V\in G(r+1, H^0(S,E))$ such that the degeneracy locus of $V\otimes O_S\rightarrow E$ is a smooth curve $C$ in $|L|$.

The claim is that the above is an open condition that is such bundles $E$ form an open subset in a family of vector bundles. How is that? Why are (a) and (b) open conditions.

I have other simpler doubts. Is the morphism $V\otimes O_S\rightarrow E$ always injective? Also how do we know that $G(r+1,H^0(S,E))$ is non-empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Condition (a) is open by semi-continuity theorem. To check openness of (b) consider a vector bundle $E$ on $S \times B$ (where $B$ is an arbitrary base scheme) and rank $r+1$ vector subbundle $V$ in $p_*E$ (where $p \colon S \times B \to B$ is a projection). By adjunction there is a natural morphism $p^*V \to E$. Let $C$ be its cokernel and $Z \subset S \times B$ its support. Then the subscheme of $B$ over which the fibers of $Z$ are $\ge 2$-dimensional is closed, and the subscheme where the fibers are 0-dimensional is empty. Therefore, the subscheme $B_1 \subset B$ over which the fibers are 1-dimensional is open. Finally, the subscheme of $B_1$ over which the fibers are smooth is open as well.

Surely we don't know that $Gr(r+1,H^0(S,E))$ is non-empty. But if it is empty the corresponding subscheme in $B$ is empty as well, but it is still open.